# Glossary/Abbreviations list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

How can I make a list as shown in the picture?

[image]

I want to have a similar list of abbreviations/notions where everything is lined up as shown in the picture. I have tried to use the `glossaries` package, but that didn't give me the dots inbetween. 
I have also tried to use `\begin{description}`, but then I had to manually enter the dots.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible either with the main glossary and using `listdotted` as glossary style or defining another special glossary for this.

Please note that `listdotted` ignores the value of the `symbol` key, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{energy}{name={$E$}, description={Energy}}
\newglossaryentry{speedoflight}{name={$c$}, description={Speed of light}}
\newglossaryentry{mass}{name={$m$}, description={Mass}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\setglossarystyle{listdotted}
\printglossary[title={Symbols}]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Christian, somehow I'm getting an additional line: latex ................. Is a markup languag especially suited for scientific documents. Is there a bug in the glossary package?

Comment: @AidanRocke: As you can see from my screen shot: There's no extra ...... line

Comment: I managed to fix this problem actually but only by inserting the glossary entries into the page where I wanted the glossary to appear.

Comment: @AidanRocke: I doubt that is the correct way to do so..

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, everything was correct but I got an extra line with latex... Could the 'correct' solution depend on the latex editor?

Comment: @AidanRocke: I don't use a `LaTeX` editor.

Answer (score 5):

An example using the [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package (borrowing from Christian's answer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

% use KOMA-Script's `labeling' list:
\usepackage{scrextend}
\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\labeling[ \dotfill]{alongwordthatdeterminesthewidth}}
  {\endlabeling}

% declare a list style for acro using the new list:
\DeclareAcroListStyle{dotted-list}{list}{
  list = mylist
}

% tell acro to use the new list style:
\acsetup{
  list-style = dotted-list
}

% declare the acronyms:
\DeclareAcronym{energy}{
  short = {$E$},
  long  = {energy}
}
\DeclareAcronym{speedoflight}{
  short = {$c$},
  long  = {speed of light}
}
\DeclareAcronym{mass}{
  short = {$m$},
  long  = {mass}
}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\printacronyms[name=Notation]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 2021/`acro` v3:

With `acro` v3 and greater the following definition in the preamble will result in the same output:

```
% use KOMA-Script's `labeling' list:
\usepackage{scrextend}
\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\labeling[ \dotfill]{alongwordthatdeterminesthewidth}}
  {\endlabeling}

% make acro's default list use the new list:
\SetupAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%
  \let\description\mylist
  \let\enddescription\endmylist
}
```