# List of Acronyms: A dotted line between the the abbreviated form and the full form

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, acro

i am using the `acro` package for the acronyms and the `\printacronyms` command to get the list of the acronyms.
What i wanted to have is a list in the following style:

**short abbreviated form .......................... full form**

The short abbreviated form is on the left side of the page, the full form on the right and both are "connected" with a dotted line.

I am confused because i thought it would be easy to get that and now i am a bit worried that i missed the easy way to do it. I was searching the last hours but didnt find anything like that. If it is not possible with the `acro` package i can use `glossaries` or acronyms, what is no problem.

I hope someone has an idea and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Does this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352516/glossary-abbreviations-list) helps you?

Comment: @Excelsior the answer there will not work with an up to date `acro`

Comment: @Excelsior Thank you very much! The solution with the ```glossaries``` package helped me a lot!

@cgnieder Yes you right with an up to date ```acro``` it does not work anymore

Comment: @Lextrus I updated the `acro` answer with a solution for an up to date `acro`.